# Remapped header from AWS Lambda response

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda

I have a web app with HTTP API deployed on AWS Lambda.
The Lambda has both AWS API Gateway proxy integration and function URL.
I'm calling it directly using function URL, without API Gateway.
One of the endpoints in microservice uses basic HTTP authentication and returns 401 in case of invalid credentials. I'm adding "WWW-Authenticate" header set to "Basic" to the 401 response, so that web browser can handle it properly.
The problem is that the header in response is remapped to "x-amzn-Remapped-www-authenticate".

I found an information that using API Gateway it's expected behaviour, but I cannot find any info how it should work using function URL directly. Is there any way to fix it and disable header remapping?